# Paystack integration in laravel

Tags: laravel, payment-gateway

I have used **unicodeveloper/laravel-paystack** package and i am facing this issue when integrating in laravel 6, even though it works fine in laravel 5 project i have integrated in, this is the error it prompts when i hit pay with paystack:

> Client error: POST https://api.paystack.co/transaction/initialize
>   resulted in a 400 Bad Request response: { "status": false, "message":
>   "Plan not found" }

Answer (score 0):

if you do have this error something try your paystack live keys to test your project